# Filemaker Database. How to import to one table then copy information to a different table and populate realted tables

Tags: database-design, import, filemaker

I'm using filemaker to create a union membership database, the problem i'm having is that you can't import files into related tables. Basically i'm trying to figure out how I could import an excel spreadsheet containing member information and dues payment information and then populate the correct member and their related table information. I read something I thought might be helpful about magic keys and tried to implement that but i'm wondering if my parent table needs to be my flat import table. [image]

Answer (score -1):

You can import the raw data to a Temporary table.
Loop through each record.
Using Magic key, you can create both parent and related records.